# Is it true that the function

Tags: analysis

Suppose that a function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ satisfies
$f(1/n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$? and show that

(a) $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ ?

(b) $f$ is differentiable $(0,1)$ ?

I think this will be true case when $f(x)$=$sin(x)$ but I am a bit confused how to prove for any function and how to use $\epsilon$ _ $\delta$ to prove that. Please if any one can help me with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: For **general** functions it is false. Example: $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is irrational, $f(x)=x$ when $x$ is rational.

Comment: Please, make a bigger effort to think of a useful title.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$